# Running rake from RubyMine on the Neo Ruby Koans

Tags: ruby, rake, rubymine

I have downloaded the Neo Ruby Koans from [Neo Ruby Koans site](http://rubykoans.com) unzipped
to a folder 'koans' and opened the folder as a new project in RubyMine (the trial version). How do I run the `rake` task, preferably with keyboard shortcuts, from within RubyMine? When I try `Alt-R` the only available rake tasks are `clean` and `clobber` plus there is an option to 'reload rake tasks'. If I go to the `koans` folder in a terminal and do `rake` I get the desired effect.

Comment: Do the rake tasks show up after you run reload rake tasks?

Comment: @alannichols No change after reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the koans and the tasks aren't showing up in the run options for the rake because they aren't commented.

If you open a terminal at the same location as the rake file and run `rake -T` it will show you the commented rake tasks only.  This is what RubyMine is doing.  If you run `rake -T -all` the other tasks will show up as well.

To get rubymine to show these tasks in the Alt-R list, check the box that says 'include undocumented' on the pop up.